# Getting its already in use error in azure while creating Azure resources

Tags: azure, subscription

I have two subscriptions subscription A and Subscription B. Both the subscriptions are under same tenant group. virtual machine A is deployed in Subscription A under one region P and resource group 1. I am trying to deploy the virtual machine in subscription B with same name as Virtual Machine in subscription A with same region but different resource group but getting "it is already in use" error. Any solution for this issue.

Comment: If you are trying to deploy a **virtual machine** with the `same name` as an existing virtual machine in another `subscription`. This error occurs because the virtual machine name must be unique within a region, regardless of the subscription or resource group. for more details refer this [link](https://build5nines.com/azure-resource-naming-conventions/)

To resolve this issue, you can either rename the virtual machine in Subscription A or choose a different name for the virtual machine in Subscription B.

Answer (score 0):

> Getting its already in use error in azure while creating Azure resources

If you are trying to deploy a **virtual machine** with the `same name` as an existing virtual machine in another `subscription`. This error occurs because the virtual machine name must be unique within a region, regardless of the subscription or resource group.

When I try to create a `virtual machine` in a different resource with the same virtual machine name, it's accepted under the **Basics** section, as shown below.

[image]

After deployment, it threw the following error, suggesting a deployment to a different location.

[image]

Refer this [link](https://build5nines.com/azure-resource-naming-conventions/) for more details